# Custom prolog/epilog functions for profiling

Tags: visual-studio, profiling, kernel

Is it possible, with Visual Studio compilers, to write 2 functions that get called before calling into other functions and after the functions have executed? In gcc you could do that with `__cyg_profile_func_*()` functions:

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *func_address, void *call_site )
                                __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function));

void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func_address, void *call_site )
                                __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function));
```

I need a solution that works for kernel mode software. I think [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) may be of help, but the free edition is 32 bit only and my drivers are pure 64 bit.

I want to generate the [call graph](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-graphvis/) for the specific code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use the [/Gh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx) [/GH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx) switch of cl to create penter/pexit hooks.
2. For free hooking APIs take a look at:
   2.1 [easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com)
   2.2 [N-CodeHook](http://www.newgre.net/ncodehook)

Comment: Thanks a lot. /Gh /GH are exactly what I need.