# How to improve this logging scheme (A little more)

Tags: c++

Basically, I have this logger class and prefixer.

```
class Logger
{
    public:
        enum LogType
        {
            LT_DEBUG = 0,
            LT_WARNING,
            LT_ERROR,
            LT_STAT,
            LT_TEXT,
            LT_INFO,
            LT_OTHER,
            LT_UNKNOWN
        };

        __attribute__((format(printf, 7, 8)))
        virtual const char* EHLog(LogType,  //LogType
                bool,                       //Send to FE
                int,                        //Error code
                const char*,                //File
                int,                        //Line
                const char*,                //Format
                ...) = 0;

        virtual void PushPrependString(const char*) = 0;
        virtual void PopPrependString() = 0;

        virtual ~Logger(){}
};

class Prepender
{
    public:
        Prepender(Logger& oLogger, const char* zPrependString)
            :o_Logger(oLogger)
        {
            o_Logger.PushPrependString(zPrependString);
        }

        ~Prepender()
        {
            o_Logger.PopPrependString();
        }

    private:
        Prepender();
        Prepender(const Prepender&);
        Prepender& operator=(const Prepender&);

        Logger& o_Logger;
};
```

Now, In the functions where any logging is done, I do this:

```
void SomeObject::SomeMethod()
{
   Prepender(*p_Logger, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

   //Do stuff
}
```

which works fine.

Is there any way to improve this by doing away with creating a `Prepender` object manually where I need logging? (Even macros?) (I do understand that it maybe impossible, I want to know what ideas others have).

EDIT: As I see lot of people getting wrong ideas, I'd ideally like to do this:

```
void SomeObject::SomeMethod()
{
   //Prepender(*p_Logger, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

   //Do stuff
   //And the same results!!!
}
```

The main motivation for doing this is to make sure that I do not forget to prefix a function when there is logging being done in it. If I did, the function reported will be one level up than the real one.

Comment: Can't you state what you do want to achieve? How would you like the client code to appear?

Comment: @Simone:"Is there any way to improve this by doing away with creating a `Prepender` object manually where I need logging?" ?

Comment: I changed my mind: it could be done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2:

Based on the revised Edit in OP, it is not possible to achieve the desired goals of logging in an portable manner at least, IMO.

EDIT1:

1. Don't you want to support wide characters?
2. Why not using string (wstring) instead of char*?
3. Logger should be either a Singleton or a Monostate (should take care of your challenge related to creating it at each function entry)
4. Is this requried to be thread safe?
5. Why not a pure virtual destructor in Logger?
6. The name logger doesn't look right. It should indicate something like LogInterface etc.
7. What about exception handling?

I can go on with a few more, until you tell us the specs!!

Comment: Hey, I am only talking about getting rid of creating a `Prepender` manually :D. Of course you can improve it. That's coded by a noob!

Comment: Oh. I got carried away by the title of the post (also)

Comment: @nakiya: You may check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949556/custom-prolog-epilog-functions-for-profiling . Sorry, but you will have to wait for other experts to get more ideas

Comment: After looking at the link you gave and thinking a little, I'm almost sure now that what I'm asking is not possible. Besides that, what about your 5th point? :). Pure virtual destructor? I thought you have to provide a destructor body no matter whether its virtual or not (Or even pure virtual).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a macro:

```
METHOD(void SomeObject::SomeMethod())
   // do your stuff...
ENDMETHOD

where:

#define METHOD(method_declaration) method_declaration \
   Prepender(*p_Logger, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); 

#define ENDMETHOD }
```

you could add something to the method's end too, if you like.

Comment: Yes but it does not solve the basic problem. If I forget to enclose the function in the macro, I may still end up logging wrong function signatures for the wrong messages. What I'd ideally like is a one-off initialization somewhere and be comfortable in thinking that prefixing will be covered. In my method and yours, I'd have to manually ensure that - There is no way of producing a compiler or a runtime error even.